# Append "_id" to foreign key fields in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    thing = models.ForeignKey('Thing')
```

Serializers and ViewSet like so:

```
class ThingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Thing


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

For MyModel list endpoint, DRF return objects like:

```
[ 
    { id: 1, thing: 1 },
    { id: 2, thing: 1 },
    { id: 3, thing: 2 },
    { id: 4, thing: 4 }
]
```

Is there a way to tell DRF to *automatically* include "_id" on the end of ForeignKey fields that are just IDs and not the actual related object? e.g.

```
[ 
    { id: 1, thing_id: 1 },
    { id: 2, thing_id: 1 },
    { id: 3, thing_id: 2 },
    { id: 4, thing_id: 4 }
]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found same request and solution here:

https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3121

https://gist.github.com/ostcar/eb78515a41ab41d1755b

The `AppendIdSerializerMixin.get_fields` override suffices for output of JSON objects (with _id appended) but when writing back to the API, it's a little more complicated and the logic in `IdPrimaryKeyRelatedField` and `IdManyRelatedField` handles that.

```
class IdManyRelatedField(relations.ManyRelatedField):
    field_name_suffix = '_ids'

    def bind(self, field_name, parent):
        self.source = field_name[:-len(self.field_name_suffix)]
        super(IdManyRelatedField, self).bind(field_name, parent)


class IdPrimaryKeyRelatedField(relations.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    """
    Field that  the field name to FIELD_NAME_id.
    Only works together the our ModelSerializer.
    """
    many_related_field_class = IdManyRelatedField
    field_name_suffix = '_id'

    def bind(self, field_name, parent):
        """
        Called when the field is bound to the serializer.
        Changes the source  so that the original field name is used (removes
        the _id suffix).
        """
        if field_name:
            self.source = field_name[:-len(self.field_name_suffix)]
        super(IdPrimaryKeyRelatedField, self).bind(field_name, parent)


class AppendIdSerializerMixin(object):
    '''
    Append '_id' to FK field names
    https://gist.github.com/ostcar/eb78515a41ab41d1755b
    '''
    serializer_related_field = IdPrimaryKeyRelatedField

    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super(AppendIdSerializerMixin, self).get_fields()
        new_fields = type(fields)()
        for field_name, field in fields.items():
            if getattr(field, 'field_name_suffix', None):
                field_name += field.field_name_suffix
            new_fields[field_name] = field
        return new_fields


class MyModelSerializer(AppendIdSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

Comment: Hey sorry to bother 2 years later, is this still the best option? I couldn't find in the DRF docs any updates that would make this simpler.

Comment: @user1777914 I don't know. I have not looked into it since then - sorry.

Comment: Almost 3 years later, is this still the best solution? Did DRF implement something to overcome this work-around?

Comment: Also curious to know if there is an elegant solution to this

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me as of today in July 2022.

```py
def ParentModel():
  ...

def ChildModel():
  parent = models.ForeignKey(ParentModel)
```

`serializers.py`

```py
def ChildSerializer():
  parent_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
      source="parent", 
      queryset=ParentModel.objects.all(), 
  )
  class Meta:
    exclude = ["parent"]
    fields = "__all__"
```

The `source="parent"` in the serializer field, is what allows this rename to happen; it needs to match the `ForeignKey` field name in `ChildModel`.

Note: The `exclude = ["parent"]` is required if you are using `fields = "__all__"` so that DRF doesn't require or return the default field name.

Note 2: If using `UUID` for your ID field then you'll need to add `pk_field=UUIDField(format="hex_verbose"),` to the serializer field you're renaming to `{field}_id`

Comment: This still works in the latest version of DRF as of January 2024. I had to use it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column) model field option in your `model`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    thing = models.ForeignKey('Thing', db_column='thing_id')
```

Or if you don't want to change your model, you can do so by changing [`source`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) serializer field in your `serializer`:

```
class ThingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    thing_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='thing')
    class Meta:
        model = Thing
        fields = ('thing_id','other_field', 'another_field')
```

Comment: I don't want to change the model. I want DRF to automatically append _id to the field name when it serializes it.

Comment: you don't need to add db_column='thing_id' for this to work. But it does required thing_id to be defined in the serializer. I'm with Matt: DRF should support this, since many other non-python clients expect *_id by convention

Comment: @tardate I think DRF does support this (i can't verify it right now; maybe later) but I am not sure why it didn't seem to work for OP.

Comment: @Ajeets it works for me, but I still need to explicity add to serializer `thing_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='thing')`. But the same does not apply for fk relationships using a SlugRelatedField. Still looking for the best general solution..

Answer (score 0):

ok matt simply add that parameter to your model class:

```
thing = models.ForeignKey(Thing, related_name='thing_id')
```

Comment: I don't want to change the model. I want DRF to automatically append _id to the field name when it serializes it.

Comment: How would configuring `related_name='thing_id'` for the `thing` attribute on `MyModel` affect `MyModel` having a `thing_id` attribute? Doesn't `related_name` determine the name of the reverse relation on the other side? (i.e. the attribute on `Thing` that points back to `MyModel`, in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be rather complicated since it's not something DRF allows to configure. But like always, you can override things.

Everything seems to happens in the [model_meta.py](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/utils/model_meta.py#L73) file. In this file, you can replace

```
forward_relations[field.name] = RelationInfo(
```

by

```
forward_relations[field.name + '_id'] = RelationInfo(
```

**Careful, you need to do it twice in that function.**

Once you've done that, you have still work to do as the [`ModelSeralizer`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L776) depends on the *real* model_meta. It appears you need to replace those three lines:

- https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L865
- https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L944
- https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L1425

Then, you need to implement a `MyModelSerializer` which overrides `ModelSerializer` and the three methods: `create`, `get_fields`, `get_unique_together_validators`. I tested it on `GET` requests and it works.

As you can see, it's a significant amount of code rewriting which implies difficulties for maintaining upgrades. **Then, I would strongly recommend to think twice before doing so.** In the mean time, you can still open an issue on the DRF project for making it more configurable (and maintainable).

Comment: Yea, that's a lot of code. Sad that DRF doesn't have this option because it becomes confusing in the REST clients to refer to "my_thing" which is actually an id and not an object - it would be much clearer if it was "my_thing_id"